# What is the fastest way to create a large lists in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance

Recently, I've been programming some sorting algorithms for fun, so I made a small function that creates a random list:

```
import random

def makelist(lengthoflist, min, max):
    return [random.randint(min, max) for _ in range(lengthoflist + 1)]
```

It's pretty efficient, but it's still slow for lists with several million elements. Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `numpy` for generating your data, here is an altered version of your function that I think reaches your goal:

```
import numpy as np

def makelistfast(lengthoflist, floor, ceiling):
    return np.random.randint(floor, ceiling, size=lengthoflist)
```

With this, trying to generate a list of 10000000 elements with some the bounds of 0 and 1 was quite a bit faster doing the following quick timing:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random

def makelist(lengthoflist, min, max):
    return [random.randint(min, max) for _ in range(lengthoflist + 1)]

def makelistfast(lengthoflist, floor, ceiling):
    return np.random.randint(floor, ceiling, size=lengthoflist)

t = time.process_time()
makelist(10000000, 0, 1)
print(time.process_time() - t)

t = time.process_time()
makelistfast(10000000, 0, 1)
print(time.process_time() - t)
```

With the output:

```
12.46875
0.015625
```